# POSIX Start new thread (task) in Clang

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, mutex, semaphore

I'm trying to understand the concept of `Mutex`, `Semaphore` in `C` language. I've been programming with `Java` over 2 years and just started to program with `C` language. I couldn't understand the `mutex`, `semaphore` concepts and usage. To be more specific, I will give an example.

Lets say I have a task which is responsible to copy file from given path to destination. And I have a forever run thread that generates files which will moved later by the task.

In `Java`, I could implement this like this;

(1) I create a `Runnable`, which takes two arg (Destination Path and Target Path) and do the moving job within it.
(2) I create another `Runnable` with forever loop, create files in it and start a new thread with `runnable (1)` and move files.

I want moving operation in another `thread` because I don't want it to block my forever thread that creates new files.

**EDIT:**
How could I implement this in `C` ?

Any comment and documents will be very helpful.

Comment: Yes, and? You can of course do the exact same thing in C. Mutexes and semaphores are synchronization primitives; they are useful when two or more threads run in parallel and want to access shared data. In your example there is no synchronization between the dispatcher thread and the worker thread.

Comment: So, simply pthread_create() method is enough.

Comment: Yes, and a call to `pthread_exit()` in the worker thread once in has completed its task.

Comment: "Any comment and documents will be very helpful" is not a question at all, much less one with the level of specificity we generally require here.  There are plenty of books covering the topics you mention; if you can't formulate a specific question then I suggest reading one of them.

Comment: Thanks @AlexP, I thought I should definitely use `semaphore` and couldn't find a way to implement.